# Runtime Cropping an Image in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, gestures, uiviewanimation

I have already selected an image from SD card in my activity's ImageView using Intent.and now I want to show a fixed size moving Rectangle i.e. we have to use gesture and whatever portion of the image we want,then we are able to crop that.How can we do that?Its really tough for me to do?
Please help me in doing that?

Update-->I have been able to bring the rectangle and I m getting problem in cropping and saving that selected part.How to do this?

Comment: you want to crop the image at your Region of interest, is this you want? clear ans plz

Comment: yes wherever I want to crop I can.

Comment: This blog post explain about [select and crop image in android](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/), hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok geetanjali. try this code this will open gallery and you can pick a photo to crop, it will store with name starts from apple, you can see cropped image in your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempFile());
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
         startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

    }

       private Uri getTempFile() {
       if (isSDCARDMounted()) {
           String f;
           muri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "apple_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
       //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"titus1.jpg");
       try {
        f=muri.getPath();
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }
       return muri;
       } else {
       return null;
       }
      }
   private boolean isSDCARDMounted(){
       String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
       return true;
       return false;
       }
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
           Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       switch (requestCode) {
       case 1:
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
           String filePath= muri.getPath();
           Log.e("path", "filePath");
           Toast.makeText(this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
           image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
           image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);


        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey above code also displays a rectangle on the selected image so that you can crop where you want

Comment: Thak you so much Titus,Its working and its perfect.I have nt implemented It that time.but nw I have done that.

Comment: Now how to save that cropped image?

Comment: A book written by rabindra nath Tagore

Comment: I even don knw the meaning?Do u?

Comment: check in SD card of the mobile it will be there start with name apple_